# Is there a way to specify a title for the contacts picker?

Tags: windows-8, contacts

The single / multiple contact pickers don't seem to have any way of specifying a title, so the user is suddenly just confronted with the big list of contacts from the people hub.

We can, of course, tell the user in advance but that adds in a level of design limitation (launching from an app bar button for example).

Am I missing the API for this as well or is this currently an unsupported scenario?

Comment: I'm trying to envision the use case where I would not give the user a visual cue that they were about to access their list of contacts.  Why would a contact list just suddenly appear without some sort of user interaction?  Not nitpicking, just trying to understand the use case and need for the feature.

Comment: This particular scenario is that you're on a page which is a list of guests. The app bar has a button with a + and the text Add guest. The text and button make it fairly clear that you're going to add a guest, admittedly I could prompt to offer options on where to select those contacts from. Once the person is on the People hub, you want to guide them to complete the task they're there for.